# SSO stopped working with Chrome 80.0.3987.116

Tags: chrome, sso

On our Sharepoint 2013 intranet our Single Sign On stopped working on Chrome when we updated from version Chrome 80.0.3987.106 to Chrome 80.0.3987.116.

Any thoughts on a fix?

Maureen

Comment: check this https://hametbenoit.info/2020/01/23/office-365-a-change-in-chrome-may-break-your-sites/#.XkxXAM5KiUk